# Normal subgroup and corresponding homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Topics in Algebra, a book written by Herstein, said the following thing on the first isomorphism theory:

> [**The book says**] Theorem 2.7.1 is important, for it tells us precisely what groups can
>   be expected to arise as homomorphic images of a given group. These
>   must be expressible in the form $G/K$, where $K$ is normal in $G$.
>   But, by Lemma 2.7.1, for any normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, $G/N$ is a
>   homomorphic image of $G$. Thus there is a one-to-one correspondence
>   between homomorphic images of $G$ and normal subgroups of $G$.

(In that book, **Theorem 2.7.1** refers to the first isomorphism theorem, and **Lemma 2.7.1** says for any normal subgroup N of G, G/N is a homomorphic image of G)

Would you check my following interpretation of Herstein's sentence?

> [**My interpretation**] Let $\Omega=\{N|N\triangleleft G\}$ and $\Pi=\mathrm{Hom}(G)/\cong$,
>   where $\mathrm{Hom}(G)$ denotes collection of homomorphism from $G$ to
>   somewhere and $\cong$ denotes isomorphism relation of groups. Then,
>   there exists one-to-one correspondence $\phi:\Omega\ni N\mapsto \{f\in\mathrm{Hom}(G)\,|\,f(G)\cong G/N\}\in\Pi$.

I found a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687317/interpretation-of-first-isomorphism-theorem) but I couldn't understand this. I am just a beginner of abstract math, so I'm sorry in advance if I use some symbols and notations strangely.

Comment: Nothing against your interpretation, but I think the sentence "Thus there is a one-to-one correspondence between homomorphic images of $G$
 and normal subgroups of $G$" is just short and clear. Yours is a bit more difficult.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for your comment. After thinking bit more, I came to suspect that my interpretaion was actually wrong. For example, let $A=\{(x, y)\in R^2|y=0\}$ and $B=\{(x, y)\in R^2| x=0\}$ be groups about usual vector's addition. In this case, $A\triangleleft R^2$ and $B\triangleleft R^2$, and $R^2/A\cong R^2/B$. Thus, by the map $\phi$ that I defined earlier, $A$ and $B$ send to the equal element of $\Pi$, which means $\phi$ is no longer be one-to-one.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Instead, I think the follwing is correct. Let $\Omega=\{N|N\triangleleft G\}$, $\Omega^{\prime}=\Omega/\cong$, and $\Pi=\mathrm{Hom}(G)/\cong$. Then, there exists one-to-one correspondence $\phi:\Omega^{\prime}\to\Pi$. 

I would be grateful if you give me comment on this.